# Precompiled Headers With GCC/GMake Causing `pragma` Warning (Premake)

Tags: c++, gcc, gnu-make, premake

In my Premake file I go:

```
pchheader("../../"..dir_root.."stdafx.h")
```

I found that this at least partially works.  (The invocation is somewhat different for ICC on Windows.)

When compiling, I get exactly one warning:

```
stdafx.h
../../mylibrary/stdafx.h:1:9: warning: #pragma once in main file
 #pragma once
         ^
```

I believe this comes from GCC compiling the precompiled header (as if it were some kind of main file).  So, this warning is (kindof?) justified.

I would rather not remove the `#pragma once` which is obviously in `stdafx.h` (although I imagine that would fix the warning), because of builds not using the PCH.

Is that my only option, or is there something else I can do?  I am tagging this both [gcc](/questions/tagged/gcc) and [premake](/questions/tagged/premake), since a solution using either (e.g. change the compile arguments, call differently into Premake) would be fine.

Answer (score 0):

Well, in C++, your main file (the file with your main function, `int main(int argc, char * argv[]`) should not have `#pragma once` because it is only for header files. So it seems as though your main function is in `stdafx.h` when it shouldn't be. If it is, put it in a .cpp file and include your header files there.

It is only a warning though, so don't fret.

Comment: Also, are you using Visual Studio? If so, generate an empty c++ project instead of a win32 application.

Comment: The warning occurs precisely when generating the PCH for `stdafx.h`. The problem is that it is generating a warning as if it were a translation unit. Also, this isn't related to project type (which affects runtime and target, not PCHes).